# First argument to Stream::create() must be a string error when using Mailgun sdk

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Mailgun php sdk to send batch mails with Mailgun php sdk however I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException  : First argument to Stream::create() must be a string, resource or StreamInterface.

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\dtcburger.com\vendor\nyholm\psr7\src\Stream.php:87

  Exception trace:

  1   Nyholm\Psr7\Stream::create(Object(Illuminate\Support\Collection))
      C:\xampp\htdocs\dtcburger.com\vendor\nyholm\psr7\src\Factory\HttplugFactory.php:29

  2   Nyholm\Psr7\Factory\HttplugFactory::createStream(Object(Illuminate\Support\Collection))
      C:\xampp\htdocs\dtcburger.com\vendor\php-http\multipart-stream-builder\src\MultipartStreamBuilder.php:61

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

This is my code:

```
$mailgun = Mailgun::create(env('MAILGUN_SECRET')); 


        $result = $mailgun->sendMessage(config('mail.mailgunDomain'), [
            'from' => config('mail.username'),
            'to' => $emails,
            'subject' => $mailData['subject'],
            'text' => 'Hi',
            'recipient-variables' => $json
        ]);
```

Comment: What does `env('MAILGUN_SECRET')` return for you? From the error message, it seems clear that it's not a string.

Comment: just checked and it's a string

Comment: I was getting this exact error message and found that the array I was sending to Mailgun had additional variables that Mailgun didn't know how to process. Make sure the array that you've built to send doesn't have any elements in it that Mailgun isn't expecting and that the string fields are really strings and not arrays.  I would keep it real simple and manually input the array values (from, to, subject, text) as a test case and see if the error disappears.